# Directory structure with php-fpm

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, mod-fastcgi

What's the best directory structure (aka "where to put websites html files") when php-fpm is running?

Actually I have one user per website (so for example there is the website `example.com` and the user `example`).

Should I put the html files inside:

- `/var/www/html/example/`
- `/var/www/html/example.com/`
- `/var/www/example/`
- `/var/www/example.com/`
- `/home/example/`

?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you set up PHP-FPM with [`mod_proxy_fcgi`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html), which is newly available in Apache 2.4 for just this type of use case, you put your `html` and `php` files and all other web content files in your document root just like any other website. The Apache [wiki entry for PHP-FPM](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM) has some good guidance to help you get up and running with the right configuration.